# Mysql сортировка по кастомному полю

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Здравствуйте.
Есть характеристики которые берутся из 3 (трех) таблиц. При выводе выглядит это так:

`ПРОЦЕССОР
 Производитель - intel
 Количество ядер - 4
 Назначение - для ноутбука`

И допустим, я забыл добавить `частота процессора`. Если я ее сейчас добавлю, то она станет последней, тоесть будит идти после `назначение`.

А вот собственно сам вопрос. Надо завести поле в таблице, в котором можно было бы указать, после какого параметра вставить новый параметр. Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Это проблемы отображения на клиенте, и к хранению данных они никакого отношения не имеют.

Comment: Ну да... В опенкарте и престашопе они от нечего делать поле `sort_order` добавили

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в таблицу характеристик поле `sort4` типа `int`. В это поле укажите произвольный порядок, затем в запросе по нему сортируйте. Не забудьте поле в индексы добавить.

Comment: Произвольный порядок это как?

Comment: примеры произвольных порядков: 
1,2,3,4    
4,3,2,1   
2,1,3,4

Comment: Нет, это тояпонял. Его автоинкрементом сделать что ли?

Comment: вот и славно, раз уж это поняли то остальное пустяки ;-)

Comment: Нет - если порядок произвольный то и задаётся он вручную при вводе данных, другими словами это порядковый номер свойства

Comment: А нельзя ли сделать как то что б в ручную не задавать а автоматом что б ставилось?) Ну типа, определяло самое высокое число и ставило +1 кпримеру

Comment: не вопрос, тогда последнее добавленное будет всегда отображаться последним :-) по другому кроме как ручным вводом программа не узнает куда вы хотите добавить, ну можно разве что добавить автоматом последней и если будет необходимость тогда вручную изменить. Узнать какое число установить чтоб стало последней можно через MAX()+1

Comment: Спасибо) теперь примерно представляю как это сделать

Comment: удач и улыбок ;-) кстати можно инкрементировать не на 1 а на 5 или 10, чтобы оставалось место для вставки между при необходимости ;-)

Comment: Да да) я так и думал сделать)